# How to simply generate a random base64 string compatible with all base64 encodings

Tags: c, random, base64

In C, I was asked to write a function to generate a random Base64 string of length 40 characters (30 bytes ?).
But I don't know the Base64 flavor, so it needs to be compatible with many version of Base64.

What can I do ? What is the best option ?

Comment: You can't do it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 lists contradictory targets, out of which the 24-bit crc makes it incompatible with the versions not supporting '=' pad character. If this rule is relaxed, then there's your specification. Hint: don't use characters 62 or 63 and use CR+LF.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen  Thanks for the link. We were not aware of crc 32, but examples we have seems to use require only 40 characters and no '='. Please elaborate on character 62 and 63. Thanks

Comment: Surely this is impossible. If you don't know the encoding, the best you could do is a Base62 encoding which (by definition) is not any Base64 encoding at all.

Comment: It means you should generate a random distribution of 40 characters from the set [0-9][a-z][A-Z], which represents a large but not complete subset of all 30-byte sequences.

Answer (score 4):

All the Base64 encodings agree on some things, such as the use of [0-9A-Za-z], which are 62 characters.  So you won't get a full 64^40 possible combinations, but you can get 62^40 which is still quite a lot!  You could just generate a random number for each digit, mod 62.  Or slice it up more carefully to reduce the amount of entropy needed from the system.  For example, given a 32-bit random number, take 6 bits at a time (0..63), and if those bits are 62 or 63, discard them, otherwise map them to one Base64 digit.  This way you only need about 8, 32-bit integers to make a 40-character string.

If this system has security considerations, you need to consider the consequences of generating "unusual" Base64 numbers (e.g. an attacker could detect that your Base64 numbers are special in having only 62 symbols with just a small corpus--does that matter?).